# How to download file by wget when file is named partially

Tags: linux, bash, regular-expression, wget

here is the way how to download weel file by `wget` and copy it to `/home/wheel.whl`

```
wget -q  http://$REPO_SERVER/WHL/wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl -O /home/wheel.whl
```

the problem is when changing the version of weel under `$REPO_SERVER/WHL/`

for example file can replaced with new version as - `wheel-0.55.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

but now `wget` will failed since `whl` file was change

so we are thinking to change the wget syntax as

```
wget -q  http://$REPO_SERVER/WHL/wheel-*.whl -O /home/wheel.whl
```

but syntax above isn't working

so I will appreciate to get advice about how to download the file that start with wheel*

is it possible to set regex in that file ?

Answer (score 1):

`wget: Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP`

You can't use `wget` with wildcards for HTTP.

You can use `wget` with wildcards for FTP though. That works for me.

```
$ wget ftp://ftp.slackware.com/pub/slackware/slackware64-current/Change*.txt
‘ChangeLog.txt’ saved
```

Comment: please give me example and regarding to wget -q  http://$REPO_SERVER/WHL/wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl -O /home/wheel.whl

Comment: I dont have ftp server only httpd server

Comment: the repo is under  /var/www/html as  /var/www/html/WHL

Comment: /var/www/html/WHL/... is locally accessible to you with wildcards -- no need for `wget` for that. But you question is asking about "downloading"?

Comment: Many package repositories offer both http and ftp services. Bottom line -- If your repo has only http service, then you're out of luck for wildcards.